# Count black pixels using red value

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code on an image who has only black/white values so that if a color is black it should be counted  but somehow the following if statement  doesn't work. Is it written correctly or Im just using a good logic here

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
{  
    Color pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
    if(pixel.R > 0)
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `R`?

Comment: *If a color is black it should be counted*? What? For black R, G,B will be `0`. You check for `>0` hence it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you you don't have any grey scale?  Maybe from anti-aliasing?

Comment: I have grey scale and used otsu threshold aglorithm to make it a black/white image, so the value of 'R' should be 0

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you are right but even converting that it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no transparency, try

```
if(pixel == Color.Black)
    ....
```

(`pixel.R>0` just checks color's `Red` component. It is `0` for `Black`.)

---

For barcodes, it might be better to use some thresholds to differentiate colors, e.g.:

```
int threshold = (255 + 255 + 255) / 2;
if (pixel.R + pixel.G + pixel.B < threshold)
    ....
```

Comment: I'm trying this, it's gone take some changes though :/

Comment: @newuserhere To minimize confusions, could you provide a sample image?

Comment: you can find it easily just type "bar code" on google :P.
I need the If statement to count the bars of bar codes

Comment: @newuserhere OK, for bar codes, in a simple scenario, checking for `Black` may work. But in the real life it might be better to use some threshold values for `R`, `G`, `B` components. Something like `if pixel.R < ... && pixel.G < ... & pixel.B  < ...)`.

Comment: I've already done it in case of blury images, using otsu algorithm, the resulting image is pure black/white